# WebStorm run npm script in tool window (Protractor)

Tags: protractor, webstorm, npm-scripts

I would like to be able to run an npm script in the Protractor tool window rather than npm. This is easily doable creating a new Protractor Run/Debug config but I need to add a command line argument which the Run config doesnt currently support.

More specifically I am trying to run

```
protractor --capabilities.chromeOptions.args=--headless --capabilities.chromeOptions.args=--disable-gpu
```

Would like to do this without modifying the protractor config file.

Essentially, I want to be able to do this without having to provide multiple config files in my project.  One for headless, one without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to specify cmd options in Protractor run configuration, please follow [WEB-25165](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25165) for updates

Comment: Thanks, following.